# Does request.getSession() set cookie into the browser?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, session-cookies

I was learning session in Servlets and doing some code stuff. I saw this:

I invoked Servlet using the URL mapping. That is:

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletSessionProject/SessionLearningPath
```

The servlet code is very simple:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Now, with this simple code (I used `doGet()`), I then opened the cookies in chrome, like this:

```
chrome://settings/cookies
```

There was I was able to see a cookie set.

I am confused. In my code I simply called `request.getSession()`. Why is this simple statement setting a cookie in the browser? I am sure that the cookie was not there before.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Session is set in the cookie. `JSESSIONID`

Web Application do trace user session using cookie but this is not the only method.
When a user does not have a session with a web application and `request.getSessin();` is called, Servlet api create a new session and a session id. This session id is used to uniquely represent and trace the user session. This session id is sent in the response as a set cookie request. That is why you are seeing the cookie after one request cycle.

Answer (score 1):

See: [request.getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession())

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the
>   request does not have a session, creates one.

Session creation will set **[session cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie)** on HTTP response message. This is the "magic" that creates cookie and transfers it to the browser.

Comment: You can call request.getSession(false) if you don't want to start a new session, in case there is no current session

Comment: request.getSession() returns the current session as said by ioseb. So it gets the cookie stored in your browser all of this happens if you've already an active session. Otherwise, when there is not any active session, request.getSession() will create a session, so it sets the session ccokie on HTTP response message and sorry for my bad English.